# Xpath to parse xml and input in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml-parsing, feed

I'm trying to use xpath in conjunction with DOMDocument to try and parse my xml and insert into a table.

All my variables are inserting correctly other than $halftimescore - why is this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

  define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
  require 'db.class.php';

  $dom = new DOMDocument();
  $dom ->load('main.xml');

  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  $queryResult = $xpath->query('//live/Match/Results/Result[@name="HT"]');
  foreach($queryResult as $resulty) {
    $halftimescore=$resulty->getAttribute("value");
  }      


  $Match = $dom->getElementsByTagName("Match"); 
  foreach ($Match as $match) {

    $matchid = $match->getAttribute("id");
    $home = $match->getElementsByTagName("Home");
    $hometeam = $home->item(0)->getAttribute("name");
    $homeid = $home->item(0)->getAttribute("id");
    $away = $match->getElementsByTagName("Away");
    $awayid = $away->item(0)->getAttribute("id");
    $awayteam = $away->item(0)->getAttribute("name");

    $leaguename = $match->getElementsByTagName("league");
    $league = $leaguename->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $leagueid = $leaguename->item(0)->getAttribute("id");


    foreach ($match->getElementsByTagName('Result') as $result) {
      $resulttype = $result->getAttribute("name");
      $score = $result->getAttribute("value");
      $scoreid = $result->getAttribute("value");
    }

    mysql_query("
      INSERT INTO blabla
        (home_team, match_id, ht_score, away_team)
      VALUES
        ('".$hometeam."', '".$matchid."', '".$halftimescore."', '".$awayteam."')
    ");

  }
```

Comment: ...and `var_dump($halftimescore);` shows...? Also please show the input XML document.

Comment: string(3) "1-3" string(3) "1-3" string(3) "1-3"

Comment: Where did you place the `var_dump()` line that showed that result? (at which line in the code)

Comment: line 42. Would you like me to include my xml in the post?

Comment: No, if you have a value then it should probably work - what gets inserted instead of the value (what do you see in the db after the operation)? Also, do you get any error messages?

Comment: Is "line 42" just before the `mysql_query()` call?

Comment: the line after the call. In my database the half time scores all say 1-3. When they should be 1-0, 2-0 and 1-3

Comment: Ahhh right. Well that's fairly easy then. Will answer in 2 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you populated `$halftimescore` outside the main loop, in a loop of its own, it will only have one value (the last value) because each iteration overwrites the previous.

What you need to do instead is run the XPath query within the main loop, with a base node of the current node, like this:

```
  // ...

  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
  /*
  Remove these lines from here...
  $queryResult = $xpath->query('//live/Match/Results/Result[@name="HT"]');
  foreach($queryResult as $resulty) {
    $halftimescore=$resulty->getAttribute("value");
  }
  */


  $Match = $dom->getElementsByTagName("Match"); 
  foreach ($Match as $match) {

    // and do the query here instead:
    $result = $xpath->query('./Results/Result[@name="HT"]', $match);
    if ($result->length < 1) {
      // handle this error - the node was not found
    }
    $halftimescore = $result->item(0)->getAttribute("value");

  // ...
```

Comment: Ah that looks right to me.. but is coming up with this error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute()

Comment: @AndrewCharlton Sorry my bad. The method chaining's probably not great anyway, give me 1 sec will edit

Comment: It works! Thanks for taking time to answer this :) I best do some more research on the subject